# How to get a valid form with a required dropdown element in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular7

I have this dropdown for the month below and I can't seem to figure out how to make the form valid using what I've tried.

```js
// my form in .ts file
this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
  gender: ['male'],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(10)]],
  month: ['', Validators.required],
  //day: ['', ],
  //year: ['', ],
  city: ['', Validators.required],
  country: ['', Validators.required],
  password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(10)]],
  confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
}, {
  validator: this.passwordMatchValidator
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
  <select [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': registerForm.get('month').errors && registerForm.get('month').dirty}" class="form-control" id="inputState1" class="form-control">
    <option hidden selected>Month</option>
    <option>Jan</option>
    <option>Feb</option>
    <option>Mar</option>
    <option>Apr</option>
    <option>May</option>
    <option>Jun</option>
    <option>Jul</option>
    <option>Aug</option>
    <option>Sep</option>
    <option>Oct</option>
    <option>Nov</option>
    <option>Dec</option>
  </select>
  <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="registerForm.get('month').dirty && registerForm.get('month').hasError('required')">Month required</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using reactive forms? Where is the formControlName directive on the input?

Comment: Hi Alexander. When I ad the formControlName "month" it validates the form if the dropdown is changed, BUT it hides the default value in the dropdown.

Comment: You absolutely need formControlName to have two way binding of the form group property. That being said, it’s probably hidden because you have the property hidden on the default option. Can you explain why you put hidden on that default value? Also you do not need selected.

Comment: Ya, because once the user selects the month I want the default value "month" to hide so that it can't be a selected option.

Comment: That would be why you'd have the `Validators.required` validation. That would prevent empty or default from being a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are defining the form programatically you are using [Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).To associate the form definition in your typescript file to the form in your template you need some angular properties:

- formGroup: for the form
- formControlName: for each form control

To make the first element in your dropdown not selectable for users you can set it as disabled.

Sample code for your template:

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
<select class="form-control" formControlName="month">
    <option value="" hidden selected>Month</option>
    <option value="1">Jan</option>
    <option value="2">Feb</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Sample code working: https://angular-reactive-form-dropdown.stackblitz.io

Comment: Hi. Yes I have those, as soon as I add the formControlName = "month" the "month"  becomes invisible in the dropdown. It has now disappeared.

Comment: I updated the code for the template, if you want to make the first element not selectable you can set it as disabled.

Comment: I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023625/adding-formcontrolname-makes-the-default-value-disappear-in-my-forms-dropdown-i