# Angular - Adding formControlName makes the default value disappear in my select dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm having trouble with my select element, when I add the formControlName then `-- Select Event Type --` doesn't show up anymore (but is still selected in the dropdown). If I remove it, it displays but doesn't validate of course.

This guy has the same issue here, but the answer does not work for me: [Adding formControlName makes the default value disappear in my form's dropdown in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023625/adding-formcontrolname-makes-the-default-value-disappear-in-my-forms-dropdown-i)

```html
<select class="form-control" name="type" id="type" formControlName="type" [appValidatedInputControl]="form.get('type')">
    <option [value]="" disabled selected>-- Select Event Type --</option>
    <option *ngFor="let type of (eventTypes$ | async)" [value]="type">{{ 'eventType.' + type | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

TS file

```js
export class EventCreationFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  //...
```

The parent HTML component where the form is injected:

```html
<app-event-creation-form [form]="form"></app-event-creation-form>
```

Parent component TS file

```js
export class EventCreationComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  form: FormGroup;
  //...

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
     this.initForm();
     //...
  }

  initForm() {
    this.form = this.eventCreationService.createForm();
    const { type, tags } = this.form.controls;
    this.subs.sink = type.valueChanges.subscribe((typeValue) => {
      if (typeValue && (tags.untouched || !tags.value || !tags.value.length)) {
        tags.patchValue([{ value: typeValue, display: typeValue }]);
      }
    });

    //...
  }
```

The EventCreationService:

```js
@Injectable()
export class EventCreationService implements OnDestroy {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  createForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.attachEventHandlers(this.fb.group(
      {
        type: [undefined, [Validators.required]],
        //...
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: In that case set the default value in the form which is source of this formcontrol

Answer (score 0):

use the [ngValue] directive with any default value (using 0 here):

```
<select class="form-control" name="type" id="type" formControlName="type" [appValidatedInputControl]="form.get('type')">
    <option [ngValue]="0" disabled>-- Select Event Type --</option>
    <option *ngFor="let type of (eventTypes$ | async)" [ngValue]="type">{{ 'eventType.' + type | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

and then in your component, (assuming your FormGroup is called `customForm`):

```
this.customForm = new FormGroup({
 type: new FormControl(0)
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. I have updated my post. I think maybe it it because my form inherits from another parent component. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the square brackets from the value.

If this does not work please create a stackblitz and try to recreate the problem.

```
<select class="form-control" name="type" id="type" formControlName="type" [appValidatedInputControl]="form.get('type')">
    <option value="" disabled selected>-- Select Event Type --</option>
    <option *ngFor="let type of (eventTypes$ | async)" [value]="type">{{ 'eventType.' + type | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
createForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.attachEventHandlers(this.fb.group(
      {
        type: new FormControl('-- Select Event Type --', Validators.required),
        //...
```

Answer (score 0):

NOT use 'selected' to show , -- Select Event Type --, at first

--SelectEventType--

And, when create the form

```
  this.fb.group(
  {
    type: [null, [Validators.required]],
    ...
  }
```

NOTE: I imagine that your `[appValidatedInputControl]` is a directive to validate the control. When you use ReactiveForms, you should use Validators not directive.